# Freeze/Lock cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a VBA to identify when a cell has been populated which then needs stop the date from ticking and moving the DUE date further away. For example, If D1 has a date of 16/10/2023, T1 = D1+28 days which in turn changes U1 to =MAX(T1-TODAY(),0). Obviously using the Today function means that the data in U1 will change every day. I have the information from U also in column AN, so if its possible, am I able to copy and then special paste that information back in to column U so that the due date no longer changes.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("P:P")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "Yes" Then
            Range("U" & Target.Row).Clear
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `Worksheet.Change` event.

Comment: It would help your question to add the code you have so far.

Comment: What's in T1 ?  And what's in D1 ?  I think you might need to revise the description to clarify things a little.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("P:P")) 'change(s) in col P?
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then                   'any cells?
        For Each c In rng.Cells                  'handle each updated cell in Col P
            If c.Value = "Yes" Then
                With c.EntireRow
                    .Columns("U").Value = .Columns("AN").Value
                End With
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```